# Applications of the annihilator

Tags: linear-algebra, education

I am currently assisting a course for future teachers at university level for a joint education in maths and physics.

We defined the annihilator for an element A of a K-algebra $\mathcal A$ as the set of polynomials over the field K, that return zero. So

$$Ann(A):=\{f\in K[x]: \tilde f(A)=0\}$$

The tilde indicates the evaluation-homomorphism. We proved that any such f can be decomposed into a unique normed polynomial h and some rest, such that every $f = g\cdot h$. This can be used to show that a nilpotent matrix of order k, has $M_A(x)=x^k$ as minimal polynomial.

My problem: it is an interesting tool to find the minimal polynomial of say a real valued matrix. But I do not see the relevance for future teachers as this seems to be "just" a technical result without any applications that one could explain to someone without extensive mathematical education.

So, are there any nice applications for this method in the realm of euclidean geometry? or physics?

I am asking to avoid the tunnel syndrom or the double discontinuity that Felix Klein complained about in 1908 for maths education. Maybe someone can give some inspiration?

Comment: This is arguably an instance of a more general pattern in algebraic geometry: it is often useful to look at a "geometric" element/set by considering the polynomials that are zero over this set and conversely to look at a collection of polynomials by considering their common zero-set.

Comment: On another note, looking at the annihilator of a linear map $A$ and its restriction to invariant subspace is helpful in deriving/considering a matrix's [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form).

Comment: Could you clarify (or point to some resources regarding) what you mean by "double discontinuity" or Felix Klein's complaint?

Comment: @BenGrossmann: It just means that future teachers come into university with school knowledge and are suddenly confronted with university level math and then go back to school not needing any of it. Felix Klein wrote about that in an article from 1924.

Comment: @PeterKeller Probably, this was a problem just emerging during Klein's time, but let's be real, very little of pure math, let us say at the level of abstraction of the annihilator is taught in schools. The purpose of future teachers learning about this stuff always seemed to me necessary because really only this type of abstraction captures the idea of modern mathematics and a teacher can only give glimpses of this in school if they themselves have learned it.

Comment: Regarding the annihilator, as Ben Grossmann pointed out, this is a more general concept in algebraic geometry. So one might even argue that using the definition as you gave it (and many (commutative) algebra texts do) shields students from having to learn some algebraic geometry to contextualize it, thus making it much more accessible.